# Computer restarts several times before shutting down - 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, restart

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a desktop PC and have the following problem:

Every time I try to shutdown the PC the monitor goes off and the computer restarts two times. After that the computer starts up and Ubuntu starts aswell. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Computer specs:

```
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4 
GPU: GeForce GTX 760/PCIe/SSE2
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z87X-OC  
RAM: 16 gigs of RAM
```

UPDATE: I read many post regarding this same topic, and still no solution has worked.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you shutdown your pc?

Comment: Out of curiosity, try shutting it down with "sudo shutdown -h now". Also, you're problem has probably been solved before, since there are many questions similar to yours here at askubuntu: https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=ubuntu%20won%27t%20shut%20down%20site%3Aaskubuntu.com

Comment: @lapisdecor I click the top right button then click Shut Down.. and select shutdown.

Comment: @Wildcard: I've read many other post, but they don't say anything about the repeating restarts. They say the computer just restarts and starts ubuntu while in my case the computer restarts 2 times and later I get the ubuntu screen.

Comment: @Wildcard: BTW I tried the sudo command you said but sadly it didn't work. I still get 2 *beep* sounds from my PC (Like when turning on the computer) and then the ubuntu login screen.

Comment: Are you sure your computer is restarting? Ubuntu might shutdown the monitor several times before it shows the login screen. What you are seeing could be the normal process.

Comment: @lapisdecor I'm sure, after I click the shut down button, the computer makes the *beep* sound (Like turning on a computer) and after that the ubuntu screen that lets me choose which OS I want to boot appears.

Comment: This might be an hardware problem.

Comment: @lapisdecor: I thought that too, the thing is sometimes it shutdowns properly but sometimes happens what I was describing.